# How avoid a scrolling show behind a header with iOS / Html / WebView

Tags: ios, css, scrollview, quasar-framework

I have an HTML page running in a webview, that has a header - list - footer.

When the list scrolls, it becomes visible behind the header, that must be static:

[image: Scroll behind header]

This is the header:

```
.q-layout-header {
  background-color: #343a40;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

This only happened in iOS devices/Simulators. On Android, it works.

Comment: Try setting cliptobounds for web view.

Answer (score 0):

In your q-layout change your view property

```
<q-layout view="lhh Lpr lff">
```

and unedit the css class u edited